# Advice on how to specify length of animated GPX video with ffmpeg/image2pipe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ffmpeg, gpx

I'm working on a personal project involving an action camera that records GPS data alongside video from an image sensor. I found an open source projected on GitHub called 'trackanimation' that uses a colored marker to trace the GPX path on a OpenStreetMaps overlay, but it appears that the project has been abandoned. I'm trying to sync the trackanimation video to the image sensor video, but when I try using video editing software to slow the GPX video down to 1%, it still ends up being shorter than the image sensor video. I've tried messing with the baked in `ffmpeg` command in make_video(), but still can't get the output video to be as long as I want it to be.

I started digging into the library source to see how the video was being created, tried tweaking a couple things to no avail.

```
import trackanimation
from trackanimation.animation import AnimationTrack

gpx_file = "Videos/20190516 unity ride #2.mp4.gpx"
gpx_track = trackanimation.read_track(gpx_file)

fig = AnimationTrack(df_points=gpx_track, dpi=300, bg_map=True, map_transparency=0.7)
fig.make_video(output_file="Videos/1-11trackanimationtest.mp4", framerate=30, linewidth=1.0)
```

```
    def make_video(self, linewidth=0.5, output_file='video', framerate=5):
        cmdstring = ('ffmpeg',
                     '-y',
                     '-loglevel', 'quiet',
                     '-framerate', str(framerate),
                     '-f', 'image2pipe',
                     '-i', 'pipe:',
                     '-r', '25',
                     '-s', '1920x1080',
                     '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
                     output_file + '.mp4'
                     )
```

I expect that I should be able to linearly "slow" the GPX video to a dynamic value based on the length of the video and the length I want it to be.

Comment: How many total frames? What length should it be?

Comment: @Gyan 28:18 is the length of the image sensor video, so that's what I'm trying to get the GPX video to be.